# Right way to use bash select menu and read together

Tags: bash, stdin

I have a text file (lst.txt), each line contains a pair of comma-seperated names:

```
file1,file2
file3,file4
file5,file6
...
```

and a script (sct.sh):

```
i=1
while read inp
do 
    echo " -- Line $((i++))"   
    file1=`echo $inp | sed -e "s/,.*$//g"`
    file2=`echo $inp | sed -e "s/^.*,//g"`

    ##### select block
    select fname in "$file1" "$file2"
    do 
        case $fname in
            $file1) echo -e "Delete $file1.\n";;
            $file2) echo -e "Delete $file2.\n";;
        esac
        break
    done
    ##### select block ends
done
```

and I run this:

```
$cat lst.txt | ./sct.sh
```

Now the problems are:

```
1. it would not wait for my reply;
2. some input lines get dropped (but if the select block is
   commented out, all lines are there).
```

`read` is here providing `select` with replies? How to make this script work?

Comment: are you reading file names from the stdin or the menu choices? you need to decide.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: I tried to read file names from a file and use them in a select menu.

Comment: you are catting the lst file to the script and it reads them from stdin, you also try to get the menu commands from the stdin in the script

Answer (score 8):

Two things.

First you can use the `$IFS` variable to make `read` split the line into fields separated by `,`.

Second you need to make `select` explicitly read from `/dev/tty` to prevent it from reading all your stdin:

```
i=1
# Use IFS to split by ,
while IFS=, read file1 file2 
do 
    echo " -- Line $((i++))"   
    ##### select block
    select fname in "$file1" "$file2"
    do 
        case $fname in
            $file1) echo -e "Delete $file1.\n";;
            $file2) echo -e "Delete $file2.\n";;
        esac
        break
    done < /dev/tty # Read from terminal
    ##### select block ends
done
```

Comment: Better yet, let `select` read from standard input (whatever that may be), and let `read` read from a different file descriptor. (`while read; do ...; done <&3`). Then feed `lst.txt` to the script with `./sct.sh 3< lst.txt`. Don't assume that standard input == the terminal.

Comment: @chepner Actually I don't assume that stdin is a terminal, and in fact, it isn't a terminal in this case. That's why I'm using `/dev/tty` as the input for select. But I see that doing so is a bit fragile. It would not work when the script wouldn't being started from a terminal. Let's say when it get's started by a cronjob. However, since the program requires user interaction it is quite unlikely that it would not run from a terminal. But feel free to post another answer, I'm not saying that this is the "best" way to do. Probably the simplest ;) ...

Comment: @chepner and @hek2mgl: Thanks for your help. @hek2mgl's answer does work here. Still something remains unsolved - when I select `1`, the echo is `Delete file1(or file3 or file5) .` , that's ok. But when I select `2`, the echo becomes `.elete file2 (or file4 or file6)`  ,  the dot is wrapped on the same line.

Comment: @avalan_che I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: @hek2mgl: In my case, this happens on both msys2 `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release (i686-pc-msys)` and linux `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Are you using Windows line endings in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at percol, fzy, smenu and friends. They'll happily take from stdin, present a user-friendly select menu with interactive filter, then pipe selected lines out again.