# Bash select statement conflict when reading in file

Tags: linux, bash

Surprisingly, I haven't been able to find this specific situation with using the Bash `select` statement in conjunction with looping through lines in a file. What I'm seeing is that the select statement doesn't block on user input, but seems to be automatically accepting each newline from the text file.

This is a simplified example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh

confirm() {
    local value=${1}
    echo "Confirm '${value}'?"
    select ans in Yes No; do
        case ${ans} in
            Yes ) break ;;
            No ) echo "Bye!" ; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
}


cat <<EOF > lines.txt
one
two
three
EOF

while read line; do
    confirm ${line} || exit 1
done < lines.txt

rm -f lines.txt
```

Output (runs through to completion without waiting for user input):

```bash
$ ./test.sh
Confirm 'one'?
1) Yes
2) No
#? #? #?
```

bash version: 5.1.8 (from RHEL 9.2)

Obviously this is due to the `select` reading from stdin which is conflicting with the reading of the file contents since if I explicitly read from the terminal, it works as expected (as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086287/8167673)

```bash
...
confirm() {
    local value=${1}
    echo "Confirm '${value}'?"
    select ans in Yes No; do
        case ${ans} in
            Yes ) break ;;
            No ) echo "Bye!" ; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done </dev/tty # explicitly read from terminal
}
...
```

I also tried directing the file read into a different descriptor and then reading from it:

```bash
...
exec 6< lines.txt
while read line; do
    confirm ${line} || exit 1
done <&6
...
```

But this produces the same result.

Ultimately, I'm hoping someone can explain why this is happening as well as a standard approach to dealing with these types conflicts. Thanks!

EDIT: Thankyou Gordon, Will, and Charles for your suggestions! Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179139/8167673) from the linked question, I've edited as follows, which works as intended:

```bash
...
while read line <&6; do
    confirm ${line} || exit 1
done 6< lines.txt
...
```

Comment: This might help: `while read line </dev/tty; do`

Comment: Your redirect via FD #6 is redirecting the entire loop (including the `select`; you need to redirect just the `read` command. See [cmo's answer at the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash/66179139#66179139).

Comment: I think `-u6` in read is the magic incantation:
`while read -u6 line; do confirm $line; done 6< lines.txt`

Comment: @Will, ...or more portably, `while read line <&6; do`

Comment: @Cyrus, don't you want `/dev/tty` to read the prompt from the user for the `select`, not when reading the line from the file?

Comment: (on a different note, `confirm "$line"`; the curly braces are optional for correctness in this context, the quotes are not)

Comment: ...one could also put `</dev/tty` on the `confirm` call; `confirm "$line" </dev/tty` would ensure that the `select` run within `confirm` reads from the user instead of from the file.